# hover effect for outside class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3 block of image. I want a css in which hover a block A transform block C and B, hovering a block B transform block A and C or hovering a block C transform block A and B 
[You can see a demo of what i want in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mtcs757/46/)

```html
<p>Hover over 7 and both 8 and 9 get styled.</p>
<div id="seven" class="box">7</div>
<div id="eight" class="box">8</div>
<div id="nine" class="box">9</div>
```

```css
#nine:hover ~ #seven,
#seven:hover ~ .box {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#eight:hover ~ .box {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#nine:hover ~ .box {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.box {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: while hovering in `#eight` `#seven` and `#nine` should take css property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery it is possible as follows:

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
  $('.box').not(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $('.box').removeClass('hover');  
});
```

```css
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

.box.hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover over 7 and both 8 and 9 get styled.</p>
<div id="seven" class="box">7</div>
<div id="eight" class="box">8</div>
<div id="nine" class="box">9</div>
```

Comment: i think he needs a css.

Comment: He has jquery in the question tags.

Comment: @Atula yes, but with css you can't select previous sibling.

Comment: It can be done with CSS !. By wrapping the div's in a container we can achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @muhammad thank you for this one its good to know js can do it

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `div`'s in a container and use the container's hover event to achieve the desired output.

Check demo in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/1mtcs757/47/)

```css
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
.wrapper:hover .box {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper:hover .box:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over 7 and both 8 and 9 get styled.</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="seven" class="box">7</div>
  <div id="eight" class="box">8</div>
  <div id="nine" class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So on hover of the parent div ALL the div's get set to black and then a following hover selector for the boxes overwrites that with a white BG. Pretty good solution and no js!

Comment: Yes. An CSS only solution!

Comment: @Pugazh there is a little problem here when you hover blank space between boxes, it highlights all of them.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman : Thanks for pointing out that. Let me try to tweak the answer!

Comment: nice solution, but seems can't not achieve the ultimate goal> <